# Fractional + Integer parts of a negative Real

Tags: elementary-number-theory

So `[x] - integer part` and `{x} - fractional part` and these work quite intuitively with positive numbers.

$
[1.7] = 1\\
\{1.7\} = 0.7
$

And when you sum up the results of both functions, you get the original number

$[1.7] + \{1.7\} = 1 + 0.7 = 1.7$

But with negatives, this happens to me

$
[-1.7] = -2 \Leftrightarrow [-x] = -[x] - 1\\
\{-1.7\} = -0.7
$

the sum just doesn't work for me anymore

$[-1.7] + \{-1.7\} = -2 + -0.7 = -2.7$

What am I missing?

Comment: The fractional part of a number is always nonnegative; $\{-1.7\} = .3$, since $-1.7$ is $.3$ more than an integer.

Comment: Oh... I think this could well be the answer, would you mind posting it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The $\{x\}$ function is defined to be $x-\lfloor x\rfloor$. Thus where you write $\{-1.7\}=-0.7$, it should be $0.3$ instead. That resolves your contradiction. Below is the graph for $\{x\}$ which is not symmetrical about the y-axis, as you were probably expecting, but it has a nice symmetry of its own as well.

[image: Graph of {x}]

Comment: Makes perfect sense. Although the lack of alignment between positive/negative values does seem weird looking.

Comment: There actually is no lack of alignment. [see the graph](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x-floor%28x%29) you probably were expecting it to be symetrical about the y axis, which you make it "aligned", but this graph is symetrical too, imo.

Comment: The graph is sure worthy to include in your answer, adds a nice detail :).

Comment: @MorganWilde okay I will. :)

Comment: @MorganWilde done. :)